# Error in Stacktrace References Old Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to publish my website to a intranet file server, but for some unknown reason a portion of the application seems to be referencing an old version of a class object.  The class initializer is throwing an error stating that a stored procedure cannot be found.  I know this is old code because that stored procedure no longer exists.

The error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'stp_EMS_BM_EmployeeMovements'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find
>   stored procedure 'stp_EMS_BM_EmployeeMovements'.

The web application runs perfectly on my local machine.  I am currently publishing to the file server using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

I have manually deleted all the files on the file server, rebuilt and published the project numerous times.  Any recommendations on what to try next would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: Check your connection string for your DB. Then go see that DB to see if the SP is there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that some dependency was not fully updated on your website as it had been on your local server. To find what is different, here are two suggestions.

1) Use WinDiff on all your files, including .dll & .exe files. Some old files could have received a new modification date without being modified. WinDiff should show what files are different in these two environments.

[image]

2) Compare the file version numbers of like files in the two environments. If the file version was revised with your latest changes, this too will show what files are different in these two environments.

[image]

Comment: I know what a stored procedure is and I know what is causing the error.  The problem is not whether or not the STP exists, but why on earth am I seeing old code that I've already overwritten.

Comment: Note: my original answer regarding stored procedures in SQL Server was replaced by an answer with two (2) suggestions on how to detect file differences between the website and the local server.